# Ambient objects in .NET

Tags: .net, design-patterns

How do i create ambient objects in .NET that are available throughout a method chain. For e.g. the TransactionScope object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the ThreadStaticAttribute or the CallContext class.

Answer (score 5):

If you are working with ASP.NET however you should look into [HttpContext.Items](http://www.odetocode.com/Articles/111.aspx) because ASP.NET engine will switch threads while processing request.